# How does `const` turn multi-parameter functions iterable by the `fix` fixed-point combinator?

Tags: functional-programming, nix, fixpoint-combinators

Have been struggling with `fix` for years, and [this](https://github.com/NixOS/nix-pills/pull/228/files#diff-9a21a68a6582ea3b462b056dd6dd1cb06cb80c938ae60906e7fcd24f7ce2f751R1-R14) made my head scratch again:

```hs
fix = f: let fixpoint = f fixpoint; in fixpoint
const = a: b: a

( fix ( const ( a: b:    a + b    ))) 1 2    #=> 3
( fix ( const ( a: b: c: a + b + c))) 1 2  3 #=> 6
```

For some reason I can't wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was massively overthinking this... To [quote Nathan Faubion](https://discourse.purescript.org/t/does-this-list-unzip-implementation-have-anything-to-do-with-the-fixed-point-combinator/3898/5?u=toraritte):

> A fixed-point combinator gives control to some higher-order function in such a way that it progresses recursively.

This is probably evident, but looks like I wasn't able to put two and two together.

`const` above can be thought of simply wrapping an input function,

```
sum = a: b: a = b
const sum  #<~> x: sum
```

and the examples can be rewritten in the following forms:

```
( fix ( const sum            )) 1 2   #=> 3

( fix ( const ( a: b: a + b ))) 1 2   #=> 3

( fix (      x: a: b: a + b ))) 1 2   #=> 3

( fix (      x: sum          )) 1 2   #=> 3
```

Writing out the evaluation steps:

```
fix f = f( f( f( ... )))

fix (x: sum) = (x: sum) ( (x: sum) ( ... )) = sum
    ---f---- = ---f---- ( ---f---- ( ... ))
```

To belabor the point, input `x` is literally ignored:

```
( fix ( x: sum )) 1 2

   ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
   ∨          --------┃-------
( (x: sum) (  (x: sum) ( ... )  )  ) 1 2
  -----------┃-------------------
             ┃
             ∨
         (  sum  ) 1 2
```

---

Putting the PureScript version here, because it looks slightly different as PureScript is strict, unlike Nix:

```
fix f a = f (fix f) a
const a b = a

( fix ( const $ \x y   -> x + y     )) 1 2   --> 3
( fix ( const $ \x y z -> x + y + z )) 1 2 3 --> 6
```

(Again, see [Nathan's reply](https://discourse.purescript.org/t/does-this-list-unzip-implementation-have-anything-to-do-with-the-fixed-point-combinator/3898/5?u=toraritte) for more details.)